# HTML 5 Audio tag - Moving the bar not functioning as expected in browsers

Tags: html, audio

I have to implement a audio player in my webpage and am using the following code.

```
 <audio preload="auto" controls>
  <source src="myfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

I get the player and its playing the file properly... but if i try to drag the slider front and back to forward or backward it is not happening. It plays song from the beginning.

But song scrubbing works perfect in my android chrome browser ! Not on my computer browsers... can someone help what the issue is ?

Comment: Did  you specified height and width of object? many times that helps.